# servlet filters not applied at all in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am a beginner in using Java Servlets. I am having some issues with my servlets.
my filters are not being applied. I have some print statements in filters, but I never see anything printed on console, indicating the filters are not applied. Moreover, my filters should turn the generated xml to Json or HTML. but it just returns the xml itself.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
        <display-name>CP130 Assignment 8</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
            <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
            <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
            <jsp-file>/Quote.jsp</jsp-file>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
            <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <filter>
            <description>Filter using XSLT to format servlet response</description>
            <display-name>CP130QuoteTransformFilter</display-name>
            <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.QuoteTransformFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <description>HTML transform</description>
                <param-name>html-transform</param-name>
                <param-value>xslt/quote2html.xslt</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <description>JSON transform</description>
                <param-name>json-transform</param-name>
                <param-value>xslt/quote2json.xslt</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <description>Plain transform</description>
                <param-name>plain-transform</param-name>
                <param-value>xslt/quote2plain.xslt</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
            <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
        </filter-mapping>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

I have triple-checked for typos in web.xml
why is my filter not applied in response? I also noticed that order of the elements matter in web.xml. If I change place `filters` above `servlet`, I get error.

**EDIT**

Filter:

```
public class QuoteTransformFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig cfg;
    private String htmlStylePath;
    private String jsonStylePath;
    private String plainStylePath;

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        cfg = fConfig;
        String styleSheet = cfg.getInitParameter("html-transform");
        htmlStylePath = cfg.getServletContext().getRealPath(styleSheet);
        styleSheet = cfg.getInitParameter("json-transform");
        jsonStylePath = cfg.getServletContext().getRealPath(styleSheet);
        styleSheet = cfg.getInitParameter("plain-transform");
        plainStylePath = cfg.getServletContext().getRealPath(styleSheet);

        cfg.getServletContext().log(htmlStylePath);
        cfg.getServletContext().log(jsonStylePath);
        cfg.getServletContext().log(plainStylePath);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // no-op
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ServletRequest requestWrapper = request;
        // Illustrate the use of a request wrapper, and the use of a request document
        if ("application/json".equals(request.getContentType()) && request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Properties props = mapper.readValue(request.getReader(), Properties.class);
            requestWrapper = new PropertyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request, props);
        }

        final CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);

        String rsType = requestWrapper.getParameter("rstype");
        if (rsType == null) {
            rsType = "html";
        }

        cfg.getServletContext().log("rsType = '" + rsType +"'");

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        final String xml = responseWrapper.toString();
        System.out.println("printing rstype = "+rsType);

        Source styleSource = null;
        String responseStr = xml;
        if (!rsType.equals("xml")) {
            // Select the appropriate sytle sheet
            if (rsType.equals("plain")) {
                System.out.println("plain");
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                styleSource = new StreamSource(plainStylePath);
            } else if (rsType.equals("json")) {
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                styleSource = new StreamSource(jsonStylePath);
            } else {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                styleSource = new StreamSource(htmlStylePath);
            }

            // Process the XML document using the stylesheet
            final StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
            final Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(sr);

            try {
                final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer;
                transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(styleSource);
                final CharArrayWriter caw = new CharArrayWriter();
                final StreamResult result  = new StreamResult(caw);
                cfg.getServletContext().log("Transforming...");
                transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
                responseStr = caw.toString();

            } catch(final TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
                cfg.getServletContext().log("Config error", ex);
                return;
            } catch (final TransformerException e) {
                cfg.getServletContext().log("Transform error", e);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(responseStr);
        response.setContentLength(responseStr.length());
        final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(responseStr);
        out.close();

    }

}
```

The URL I tried for GET request is:

```
http://localhost:8080/StockQuote/Quote.jsp?symbol=GOOG&rstype=plain
```

Comment: Show us the filter code and an example of a request you made (URL and other relevant details).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: added them above.

Comment: You're using the `ServletContext` to log your messages. Where is that sent? Have you checked it? Have you tried debugging your app and stepping through the code? Have you tried changing the Filter code to throw an exception and seeing if the exception comes up?

Comment: I inserted print statements in the code above to see if it gets printed on the console. but nothing gets printed out. I will check the log files. throwing an exception in filter code is a good idea. let me check that now

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I tried throwing exception in init method of filter. But no exception is thrown. I am also finding that index.jsp is not loaded at http://localhost:8080/StockQuote/. The page is just empty

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of mistakes in your web.xml. I don't know why it didn't throw a parse exception. May be it is and you are not seeing it.

1. You can't have `servlet-class` element in `servlet-mapping` in must be inside `servlet`.
2. You can either have `jsp-file` or `servlet-class` not both.
3. The filters should be defined before Servlets
4. And better use `**` at the end of `url-pattern` when there is query strings associated

   ```
   <web-app>
       <display-name>CP130 Assignment 8</display-name>
       <filter>
           <description>Filter using XSLT to format servlet response</description>
           <display-name>CP130QuoteTransformFilter</display-name>
           <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.QuoteTransformFilter</filter-class>
           <init-param>
               <description>HTML transform</description>
               <param-name>html-transform</param-name>
               <param-value>xslt/quote2html.xslt</param-value>
           </init-param>
           <init-param>
               <description>JSON transform</description>
               <param-name>json-transform</param-name>
               <param-value>xslt/quote2json.xslt</param-value>
           </init-param>
           <init-param>
               <description>Plain transform</description>
               <param-name>plain-transform</param-name>
               <param-value>xslt/quote2plain.xslt</param-value>
           </init-param>
       </filter>
       <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
           <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
       </filter-mapping>
       <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp**</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>
       <servlet>
           <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
           <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
           <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>            
           <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp**</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
   ```

Comment: regarding point 2) do you mean for the entire web.xml, I should have only `jsp` file or `servlet-class` correct?

Comment: No. Per Servlet/Servlet mapping you can have One Servlet Class or JSP

Comment: To make it clear, for every servlet/servlet-mapping combination, I should have either JSP or servlet class correct? and I am facing a weird problem now. I started the tomcat server. it is not displaying root anything on the root `/`. It should display the welcome page of `tomcat`. I tried `localhost:8080`. The page is just empty. No error or anything on page

Comment: I fixed the above. but right now, it is not loading welcome page

Comment: That means you still have errors. Check the logs and tomcat console while starting up